# Sinatra: helper and ruby range

Tags: ruby, sinatra, range

I was trying to use a range to iterate over in Sinatra.

when I try something like

```
helpers do
  def iteration
    (1..6).each do |x|
       x
     end
  end
end
```

and call the helper from my app, it print 1..6

if i change to

```
 (1..6).to_a do #...
```

it print 123456

is that normal? or do i need to require something more in my app to be able to use range?

Answer (score 2):

You'd still need to call `each`:

```
(1..6).to_a.each do ...
```

In your helper method you don't actually *do* anything. The `iteration` method will just return the result of the last statement in the method; `each` returns the argument passed to it, so that's what gets displayed.

Comment: I know it doesn't do anything, I was just testing the thing. I tried with to_a as Sinatra doesn't seem to understand each on a range, and i wanted to check if this is true. To my surprise it does iterate over the array without the call to each.

Answer (score 2):

```
helpers do
  def iteration
    (1..6).each do |x|
       x
       #it dosen't mean output the 123456, this just let the method return a value 1..6
       #in other words, it still iteras the array in backgroud, 
       #but not outputs in terminal, you can't see it.

       print x
       #it prints 123456, really
     end
  end
end
```

## Edit

In Sinatra, you can do that as the following

```
get '/t' do
    #it will output the 123456
    body = ""
    (1..6).each do |x|
        body << x.to_s
    end
    body
end
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way to output html code from a helper with Sinatra (could use markaby but i have to wait for IT dpt to decide if they install it or not). so I wanted to loop through a range to output markup. but couldn't make the thing work in sinatra. fine in irb though.

Comment: Or, using the template in Sinatra as your post of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a way to output html code from a helper with Sinatra (could use markaby but i have to wait for IT dpt to decide if they install it or not). so I wanted to loop through a range to output markup. but couldn't make the thing work in sinatra. fine in irb though.

In the end this is what I did

```
def tag_iterator
  (1..6).map  do |x|
    "<p>#{x}</p>"
  end
end
```

In the template:

```
__END__

@@index  
%h1= @title
.test
   %div= "#{tag_iterator}"
```

And now it iterate through the range normally. I guess Ruby is a bit too much magical for me, I can spend hours guessing how things work :^P

Comment: `each` is executed purely for its side-effect (e.g. printing to the screen with `puts`) and you had none in your original post. `map` on the other hand is used to collect the values the block returns (hence the `collect` alias for it) and so you actually end up with what you wanted. No magic of any kind involved. BTW: your original example printed `1..6` because `each` returns the object it was called on.

Comment: You are welcome! :-) There are some excellent Ruby resources online, like RubyLearning, Code School etc., maybe you want to use one of them to jump start your Ruby learning.